# Printing permutations of N elements with nr_values in C

Tags: c, permutation

I am working on a assignment and it says that i need to print the values of N elements with `nr_values` in each element.

So the output should be.. So like for example Number of `elements(N) = 2`
 and the number of values each element can `hold(nr_values) = 2`

So the values are:

```
 0 0
 0 1 
 1 0
 1 1
```

Now the problem is that i am not able to make it stop after i reach the final set of values.

Following is the code that i am working on..

```
    while(flag == 0)
        {
         recursive_helper_perm_rec_1(a,N,nr_vals);
         int incrementIndex;

      for(int i = (N-2); i >= 0; i--)
      {
        if(a[i] < (nr_vals-1))
        {
            a[i]++;
            incrementIndex = 1;
            break;
        }

    }
    for(int i = (incrementIndex + 1); i<N; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == (nr_vals-1))
        {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }  




    for(int i=0; i<N ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == (nr_vals-1))
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to understand your question correctly. Do you need to print all binary numbers having N digits. (From the example provided I am just able to understand that)

Comment: @SumitTrehan No actually you are given two values i.e. N and nr_values. And in that N means the number of spots or digits i can have. And nr_values means the number values i can hold in each spot or digit. And these values have to start from 0 to N-1 and 0 to nr_values-1. And i have to perform the premutation with that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loops, a simpler implementation would be the use **recursion**.

Say you have `nr_values = 4`, `N = 3`. The possible values for each position would be `{0, 1, 2, 3}` with 3 positions `__ __ __`:

Heres a clue on how you can implement your recursive algorithm:

> Finding all the permutations `(_ _ _)` is equivalent to:
>
> Looping through the possibilities for the first digit `x = 0, 1, 2, ..`, and then finding all the permutations of the remaining digits `x (_ _)`...

I have attached a simple solution here (in case you get stuck). But **you should try coming out with your own algorithm using the concept above,** as it is always more meaningful to solve it on your own!

In your main:

```
f(N-1, 0, nr_values, N);
```

And for the `f(..)` function:

```
void f(int N,  int ans, int nr_values, int specifier) {

    int i; //i is a looping variable

    if ( N == -1 ) { //base case
        printf("%0*d\n", specifier, ans); //print leading zeros
    } else {
        for (i=0; i < nr_values ;i++) {
           f(N-1, ans+i*pow(10,N), nr_values, specifier); //append the last digit to the integer
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement a backtracking algorithm. I have written the below code for the same. I have divided the code into many functions for better understanding and readability.

- The solution vector is a[N], where each element will be filled via the `backtrack`() function.
- `get_candidates()` will return the possible number of candidates and candidates[] vector for a given slot `k`.
- `is_a_solution`() will return true if the solution vector is filled up (i.e. a[] has N elements filled).

.

```
#define  TRUE  1
#define  FALSE 0
#define  M  5 /* Possible values */
#define  N  4 /* No of slots */
typedef short int bool;

void get_candidates (int a[], int k, int *n_candidates, int candidates[])
{
    int possible[M];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        possible[i] = TRUE;
    }

    *n_candidates = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        possible[a[i]] = FALSE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (possible[i] == TRUE) {
            candidates[*n_candidates] = i;
            *n_candidates = *n_candidates + 1;
        }
    }   
}

bool is_a_solution (int a[], int k)
{
    return (k == N);
}

void process_solution (int a[], int k)
{
    /* We will just print it */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

void backtrack (int a[], int k)
{
     int i, n_candidates = 0;
     int candidates[M];

     if (is_a_solution(a, k)) {
         process_solution (a, k);
         return;
     }

     get_candidates (a, k, &n_candidates, candidates);
     for (i = 0; i < n_candidates; i++) {
          a[k] = candidates[i];
          backtrack (a, k + 1);          
     }        
}

int main ()
{
     int a[N];
     backtrack (a, 0);
}
```